# Group map values but keys are same

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a map like this. `Map<long,List<Student>> studentMap`

Key is a number 1,2,3,4...
Student object is :

```
public class Student {
 private long addressNo;
 private String code;
 private BigDecimal tax;
 private String name;
 private String city;

 // getter and setters` 
}
```

What i want to do is to convert it `Map<long,List<StudentInfo>> studentInfoMap` object and group id, addressNo and code fields.I want key are same for both maps.

I can group the map by using these codes but summingDouble is not working for BigDecimal.Also I cannot convert my studentMap to studentInfoMap.:(

```
 studentInfoMap.values().stream()
            .collect(
                     Collectors.groupingBy(StudentInfo::getCode, 
                     Collectors.groupingBy(StudentInfo::getAddressNo, 
                     Collectors.summingDouble(StudentInfo::getTax))));
```

My studentInfo object is :

```
public class StudentInfo {
  private long addressNo;
  private String code;
  private BigDecimal tax;

  // getter and setters` 
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify if StudentInfo is essentially the same as a Student, except that it is missing name and city? Or is StudentInfo a summary of multiple students who live in the same city? Without specifying the relationship between StudentInfo and Student, you can't really expect a solution here.

Comment: I just want to create a new Object(StudentInfo) with some fields of Student.But I want to group addressNo and code fields

Comment: "Grouping" in the Java Map sense means to use them as map keys. The corresponding value will be a list of Objects within that grouping. (Think of labelled buckets into which you classify things - the label is the key, the contents are a `List` of things). If you want both attributes on the label (in the key), you will first need to create a composite key Object that implements both `equals()` and `hashCode()` to conform to the `Map` contract. If that's not the "grouping" that you have in mind, please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one-to-one conversion from Student to StudentInfo:

```
class StudentInfo {
    public static StudentInfo of(Student student) {
        StudentInfo si = new StudentInfo();
        si.setAddressNo(student.getAddressNo());
        si.setCode(student.getCode());
        si.setTax(student.getTax());
        return si;
    }
}
```

To convert from one `Map` to the other:

```
Map<Long,List<Student>> studentMap = ...
Map<Long,List<StudentInfo>> studentInfoMap = studentMap.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, //same key
                    entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                            .map(StudentInfo::of)    //conversion of Student to StudentInfo
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()) //or simply `.toList()` as of Java 16
                    ));
```

**Now your grouping....**

From the JavaDoc for `java.util.stream.Stream<T> public abstract <R, A> R collect(java.util.stream.Collector<? super T, A, R> collector)`:

> The following will classify Person objects by city:
>
> ```
> Map<String, List<Person>> peopleByCity
>     = personStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCity));
> ```
>
> The following will classify Person objects by state and city, cascading two Collectors together:
>
> ```
> Map<String, Map<String, List<Person>>> peopleByStateAndCity
>     = personStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getState,
>                                                  Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCity)));
> ```

Note how the last example produces a `Map` with another `Map` as its values.

Now, `summingDouble` over StudentInfo::getTax produces a `BigDecimal`, not a Map. Replacing with `groupingBy` will work to classify Students that have the same amount for `getTax`:

```
Map<String, Map<Long, Map<BigDecimal, List<StudentInfo>>>> summary = 
      studentInfoMap.values().stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)  //YOU ALSO NEED THIS
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(StudentInfo::getCode,
                            Collectors.groupingBy(StudentInfo::getAddressNo,
                                    Collectors.groupingBy(StudentInfo::getTax)))
            );
```

**Edit: Retaining the 1,2,3,4 original keys**

To retain the original keys you can iterate or stream the original entrySet, which contains both key and value:

```
Map<Long,Map<String, Map<Long, Map<BigDecimal, List<StudentInfo>>>>> summaryWithKeys =
        studentInfoMap.entrySet().stream() //NOTE streaming the entrySet not just values
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, //Original Key with toMap
                                entry -> entry.getValue().stream() //group the value-List members
                                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(StudentInfo::getCode,
                                        Collectors.groupingBy(StudentInfo::getAddressNo,
                                                Collectors.groupingBy(StudentInfo::getTax))))
                    ));
```

**Just as an exercise, if you want a flat map (`Map<MyKey,List>`) you need a composite key `MyKey`**

As per my comment, if you are looking to have a single flat Map, you could design a composite key, which would need to implement both `equals()` and `hashCode()` to contract. For example, this is what [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) would generate for `StudentInfo` (yes, its easier to depend on lombok and use `@EqualsAndHashCode`):

```
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if(o == this) return true;
        if(!(o instanceof StudentInfo)) return false;
        final StudentInfo other = (StudentInfo) o;
        if(!other.canEqual((Object) this)) return false;
        if(this.getAddressNo() != other.getAddressNo()) return false;
        final Object this$code = this.getCode();
        final Object other$code = other.getCode();
        if(this$code == null ? other$code != null : !this$code.equals(other$code)) return false;
        final Object this$tax = this.getTax();
        final Object other$tax = other.getTax();
        if(this$tax == null ? other$tax != null : !this$tax.equals(other$tax)) return false;
        return true;
    }
    
    protected boolean canEqual(final Object other) {return other instanceof StudentInfo;}
    
    public int hashCode() {
        final int PRIME = 59;
        int result = 1;
        final long $addressNo = this.getAddressNo();
        result = result * PRIME + (int) ($addressNo >>> 32 ^ $addressNo);
        final Object $code = this.getCode();
        result = result * PRIME + ($code == null ? 43 : $code.hashCode());
        final Object $tax = this.getTax();
        result = result * PRIME + ($tax == null ? 43 : $tax.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
```

You might then use StudentInfo as the composite key as follows:

```
Map<Long, List<Student>> studentMap = ...
Map<StudentInfo,List<Student>>> summaryMap = studentMap.values().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(StudentInfo::of))
));
```

This means that you now have a nested map referenced by the composite key. `Student`s that have exactly the same addressNo, code and tax will be part of the List referenced by each such key.

**Edit: Retaining original keys**

Similarly, if you wanted to retain the original keys, you could either add them into the composite key, or similar as above:

```
Map<Long, List<Student>> studentMap = ...
Map<Long, Map<StudentInfo,List<Student>>>> summaryMap = studentMap.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                         Collectors.groupingBy(StudentInfo::of)))
));
```

Comment: Thank you very muck.First section is working(to convert it to studentInfoMap ) but grouping section is not working because keys of studentMap(1,2,3,4..) is absent.

Comment: I have added corresponding sections to both the 'standard' and flattened/composite key examples.

Comment: it gives The type Map.Entry does not define getKey(StudentInfo) that is applicable here on Edit: Retaining the 1,2,3,4 original keys section.:(

Comment: yes, sorry, need to use toMap and stream the List as when converting. You could actually do the conversion and mapping in a single step, can you figure out how? (Hint: replace the `.collect(Collectors.toList())` call in the conversion code with the last one from 'retaining 1,2,3,4 keys' and amend the resulting type declaration)

Comment: Thank you very much.I will try it

Answer (score 0):

```java
Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, studentInfoMap.values().stream().map(
    student -> student.getAddressNo()
  ).collect(Collectors.toList()));
map.put(2, studentInfoMap.values().stream().map(
  student -> student.getCode()
).collect(Collectors.toList()));
// and so ...
```

Comment: How to convert studentMap to  studentInfoMap?

Answer (score 0):

To convert the map from Student to StudentInfo, whilst keeping the same keys, you could  do something like this:

```
Set<Long> keys = studentMap.keySet();
List<Long> keylist = new ArrayList<>(keys);
Map<Long, List<StudentInfo>> studentInfoMap = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++){
    long key = keylist.get(i);
    List<Student> list = studentMap.get(key);
    List<StudentInfo> result = new ArrayList<>();
    // Create the new StudentInfo object with your values
    list.forEach(s -> result.add(new StudentInfo(s.name())));
    // Put them into the new Map with the same keys
   studentInfoMap.put(key, result);
}
```